# "Error in UseMethod("xml_add_child") " test_dir doesn't work

Tags: r, testing, testthat

When I try to define a path in test_dir function it says that error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xml_add_child") : no applicable method for 'xml_add_child' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

My testthat.R file has this lines:

```
library(testthat)
library(package)

options(testthat.junit.output_file = "test-out.xml")
test_dir("tests/testthat/0_utils/", reporter = 'junit')
test_package("package")
```

My tests are in 'tests/testthat/0_utils' folder. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

To solve this issue, you have to make sure that all your tests starts with a `context()` in the first line.

Comment: Literally the first line. Having a `library(xxx)` above the `context()` leads to this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this error if you have multiple tests, and you have the same context() in more than one of them.